# Is there any way to deselect few variables by using their names in pivot_longer function in tidyr in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, tidyr

Is there any way we can select all variables in cols argument in pivot_longer function but deselect some variables and select the rest.

```
pivot_longer(data_frame, cols=everything()-A_variable-B_variable,names_to="Names",values_to="Values")
```

Comment: Can't you pipe `data_frame%>%select(-A_variable,-B_variable)%>%pivot_longer(etc)`?

Comment: am prety sure `data_frame%>%pivot_longer(-c(A_variable,B_variable))` should work

Comment: Try defining the selection like this: `cols=-c(A_variable, B_variable)` or `cols= c(-A_variable, -B_variable)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest way is to remove the unwanted columns first with `select` and then reshape everything else to long format.

Here is an example with built-in data set `mtcars`. The *de-selected* columns are `vs` and `am`.

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
  select(-vs, -am) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = "Names",
    values_to = "Values"
  )
## A tibble: 288 x 2
#   Names Values
# * <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 mpg    21   
# 2 cyl     6   
# 3 disp  160   
# 4 hp    110   
# 5 drat    3.9 
# 6 wt      2.62
# 7 qsec   16.5 
# 8 gear    4   
# 9 carb    4   
#10 mpg    21   
## … with 278 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas, I tried ```pivot_longer(data_frame, cols=c(-A_variable,-B_variable),names_to="Names",values_to="Values")``` and it worked..